# Joining entities with @ManyToMany relationship

Tags: jpa, join, many-to-many

I have these entities:

- User
- Role
- Permission

A user has many roles and a role has many permissions.

What is the best way to retrieve a set of permission a user has?

I need a method to check if a User has a particular Permission.

This is what I have so far:

```
public boolean hasPermission(String permissionString) {
    if (!authenticated) return false;
    for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
        for (Permission permission : role.getPermissions()) {
            if (permission.getName().equals(permissionString)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

A second, but related question -- where should I put the code that checks if a user has a particular permission?

- In the User entity?
- In the UserBean EJB?
- In the Authentication JSF Managed Bean?

Comment: That's the way to do. What's the question? With the information you have given and the relationship hierarchy that's the only way to loop through. Where do you need help?

Comment: @KarthikR Was just wondering if that would be very inefficient, instead of a JOIN on the tables using EJBQL or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your mappings, the number of objects in the list, if the lists have already been fetched, your database connections, the database tuning etc.
You would have to try with production data to determine what ways are best.

For instance, If your collections have been prefetched with a join query, then traversing them in Java is trivial.  If they haven't, each access in the for loop would cause a query to populate the objects.  If it is the last one all the time, it means your java code causes you to traverse your object graph in the worst way possible and it would have been better to fetch it upfront.  So you would be losing any benefit of lazy access, and would be better of hitting the database once to query for the permission linked to this user with the permissionString name: "Select p from u User join u.roles r join r.permissions p where p.name = :permissionName".

Only testing on production data will give you the best answer for your situation, and numerous other decisions in the application and mappings change the outcome.